# Auction model time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have a basic algorithm of a double-auction mechanism which I am having difficulty finding the Big-O time complexity for. What steps should I take to to rigorously analyse this algorithm?

I know the Big-O notation is a notation for the time complexity of an algorithm, and that it represents the upper bound of the limit of the scaling factor of the algorithm.

However, I am not sure how you would get the second function to define an upper bound to my algorithm.

```
While (r = min(supply, demand)) {
    oa = Pul;
    ob = Pll;
    While {true} {
        nondetermistic choice;
        If (a buyer submits a bid:) {
            If (bid = ob or out of [Pll, Pul]) {
                bid is an invalid bid;
            } else { 
                bid updates ob and becomes a new ob;
            }
            If (ob = oa) {
                Pt = oa;
                The round is ended;
            }
        } ElseIf (a seller submits an ask:) {    
            If (ask = oa or out of [Pll, Pul]) {
                ask is an invalid ask;
            } else {
                ask updates oa and becomes a new oa;
            }
            If (ob = oa) {
                Pt = ob;
                The round is ended;
            }
        } Else (time out:) {
            If (no new oa or ob in a pre-specified time period) {
                The round is ended with no transaction;
            }
        }
        end nondetermistic choice ;
    }
    r = r + 1;
}
```

Comment: Your pseudo algorithm is too peculiar! Please turn it into pseudo code **`(improvise by putting brackets,braces,etc. at respective places for clear differentitation)`**,it's totally unclear to me as to where the loop is terminating,etc.

Comment: In some places, you are indenting by 1 space, in others, 4. It doesn't help to use double-spaced pseudo-code. These are unnecessary obstacles you are placing in front of anyone trying to figure out what you are doing. Please use sensible formatting.

Comment: I edited the code, I hope its a bit clearer and sensible

Comment: I went ahead and cleaned up your indentation and formatting for you. Some things to keep in mind:   when indenting, you should always try to indent each new "level" of code by a consistent amount. Generally, most people are used to parens being used to wrap conditions for if/while conditions, not curly brackets. You should also probably edit your code to clarify what exactly each variable is -- It's unclear what exactly `r`, `oa`, `ob`, `Pll`, `Pul`, and the like are supposed to be.

Comment: It's still not clear enough what the pseudocode is supposed to do to discuss its time complexity. Why not post actual code?